# write a function x and n, and returns h(x, n). Using for loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function in R that takes two arguments, x and n, and returns h(x, n)

Does anyone know how to do this using a for loop?

The function I am working with is: x^0 + x^1 + x^2...x^n

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want maybe this (without a for loop is better):

```
  f1<-function(x,n){

    return(sum(x^seq(1:n)))

  }

  f1(2,8)
[1] 510
```

Comment: Thanks for help.

Comment: You are welcome!